# getting values from multdimensional array using a point

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array like this :

```
int[,] map = new int[4,4];
```

and I use a lot of Points in my code, so when I want a value of the array :

```
void Something(Point start){
    int val = map[start.X, start.Y];
    // the rest of the code
}
```

Is there anyway I can just get the required value from my array using the Point directly like this :

```
int val = map[start];
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

If this is .NET 3.5+ that you are using you can create an extension method to get the data:

```
public static class ExtensioMethods
{
    public static int Get(this int[,] array, Point p)
    {
        return array[p.X, p.Y];
    }
}
```

And the use it in your code like this:

```
int val = map.Get(start);
```